# Is embedding WebKit the right solution for displaying lists of hyperlinked objects and images in an Android application?

Tags: android, html, listview, webkit

From what I've read you can embed WebKit into your Android client application and even respond to certain events that occur inside the WebKit browser.  I'm going to be making requests to a server side API that will return lists of items.  Each item will contain a hyperlink, a descriptive blurb, and a small icon image that I also want to be hyperlinked.  I want to present the user with a list of items in a typical format as follows {icon : blurb text : hyperlink for more information}.

Is embedding the WebKit and generating appropriate HTML to feed to the WebKit browser the best solution?  Or is there an Android widget that does just this and hopefully gives me solid integration to any user events generated by by the user interacting with the list?

-- roschler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android view you are asking about is the [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), which does use WebKit to render the HTML.  That's going to pretty much look like what it is - a web page, rendered inside of your application.  Depending on what the rest of your app does, that can work fine, and it can also be an incremental step towards a fully native client.  If you want to write a richer app that makes use of other native UI elements, you can just use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html), which is a very common thing to do and would allow you to easily handle all sorts of UI interactions.